# How can I change this code to show a hidden form with a menu drop down instead of a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, forms, hide

This code is working great, but I'd like to change it so it uses a drop-down menu choice instead of a checkbox.  For example, the Dropdown menu choices for "More?" would be "yes" or "no".  If "yes" is selected in the menu, I then want the hidden div to show just like it does when one checks the checkbox in the current code.

The javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function showhidefield()
  {
    if (document.frm.chkbox.checked)
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
 <form name='frm' action='nextpage.asp'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" onclick="showhidefield()">
  Check/uncheck here to show/hide the other form fields
  <br>
  <div id='hideablearea' style='visibility:hidden;'>
    <input type='text'><br>
    <input type='submit'>
  </div>
  This is a text line below the hideable form fields.<br>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your checkbox with

```
<select name="more" onchange="showhidefield()">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

And replace the

```
if (document.frm.chkbox.checked)
```

in your `showhidefield()` function with

```
if (document.frm.more.value == 'yes')
```

Comment: Oh gosh, this is very close to working thank goodness. I can't seem to do a carriage return without this saving.

Comment: I changed this part:

  `<option value="">More?</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>`

And now it works great and shows the hidden form when I select "Yes" in the menu!

I also have another part of code that make the hidden option areas become "required" similar as shown below. It works with some jquery validation I have running.

'newsletter.group': {
required: "#newsletter4:checked",
minlength: 1

Can I change "checked" to something else that will work with the menu option of selecting "yes" instead of the former checkbox value being "checked"?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name='frm' action='nextpage.asp'>
  <select name="chkbox" onChange="showhidefield(this)">
     <option value="0" selected="true">-Select-</option>
    <option value="1">Yes</option>
    <option value="2">No</option>
  </select>
  Check/uncheck here to show/hide the other form fields
  <br>
  <div id='hideablearea' style='display:none;'>
    <input type='text'><br>
    <input type='submit'>
  </div>
  This is a text line below the hideable form fields.<br>
</form>
```

And javascript code is:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function showhidefield(that)
  {
    if (that.value == 1)
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("hideablearea").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, I got exact problem.
you are using visibilty property and trying to set display now my code will work

Comment: Thank you, Gaurav!  I have the code working with techfoodar below.  Now I'm just trying to make the choices "required" with the jquery validate I'm using. I'm new to this forum so I'm not sure how to properly share that code though.